# How to think about vector fields

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, intuition

How do you imagine vector fields in a "physical" way? I'm learning vector calculus, and most of the analogies break down:

- If I imagine the vector field as some sort of fluid flow, then if it's incompressible then the divergence is clearly zero everywhere. But for most vector fields the divergence is not zero, and I find compressible fluids very counterintuitive.
- If I imagine them as electric field of some configuration of charges, but then not all vector fields corresponds to the electric field of a configuration of charges (eg the field $f(x,y) = x \hat{i} + y \hat{j}$), so those fields are again counterintuitive.

Which way should I think about them so that things like divergence/curl become obvious and the analogy doesn't break down for some cases?

Comment: PS: What are some good books to learnt the necessary multivariable calculus rigorously (not skipping the proof of eg Green's theorem) as quickly as possible for complex analysis background ? The first chapter of Griffiths EM contains some nice intuition but sadly totally devoid of proofs.

Comment: I love me some good ol' Rudin. That is, of course, if you like suffering like I do. But, if you can get through the exercises, it's hard to get a better understanding of the material (the material you'd care about would be chapters 10&11)

Comment: Another book I like a lot, not nearly as rigorous, is "Div, grad, curl, and all that: an informal text on vector calculus"

Comment: Spivak’s “calculus on manifolds” is a masterpiece.

Comment: An example of a compressible fluid is air.

Comment: So you are comfortable with two types of vector fields: divergence-free (incompressible fluids) and curl-free (potentials). Now smooth vector fields are the sum of a divergence-free part and a curl-free part, so it behaves like  a fluid plus a potential.

Comment: @Chrystomath Isn't potential a scalar field ?

Comment: A curl-free vector field is the gradient of a potential, which I hastily called just a potential.